# Create a new sparse matrix from the operations of different rows of a given large sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Lets say , S is the large scipy-csr-matrix(sparse) and a dictionary D with key -> index(position) of the row vector A in S & values -> list of all the indices(positions) of other row vectors l in S. For each row vector in l you subtract A and get the new vector which will be nothing but the new row vector to be updated in the new sparse matrix.

dictionary of form -> { **1 : [4 , 5 ,... ,63]** }
then have to create a new sparse matrix with....

new_row_vector_1 -> S_vec**1** - S_vec**4**

new_row_vector_2 -> S_vec**1** - S_vec**5**

.

new_row_vector_n -> S_vec**1** - S_vec**63**

where S_vecX is the Xth row vector of matrix S

[Check out the pictorial explanation of the above statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM0jK.jpg)

Numpy Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = np.array([[1,5,3,4],[3,0,12,7],[5,6,2,4],[4,6,6,4],[7,12,5,67]])
>>> s
array([[ 1,  5,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  0, 12,  7],
       [ 5,  6,  2,  4],
       [ 4,  6,  6,  4],
       [ 7, 12,  5, 67]])
>>> index_dictionary = {0: [2, 4], 1: [3, 4], 2: [1], 3: [1, 2], 4: [1, 3, 2]} 
>>> n = np.zeros((10,4)) #sum of all lengths of values in index_dictionary would be the number of rows for the new array(n) and columns remain the same as s.
>>> n
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> idx = 0
>>> for index in index_dictionary:
...     for k in index_dictionary[index]:
...             n[idx] = s[index]-s[k]
...             idx += 1
... 
>>> n
array([[ -4.,  -1.,   1.,   0.],
       [ -6.,  -7.,  -2., -63.],
       [ -1.,  -6.,   6.,   3.],
       [ -4., -12.,   7., -60.],
       [  2.,   6., -10.,  -3.],
       [  1.,   6.,  -6.,  -3.],
       [ -1.,   0.,   4.,   0.],
       [  4.,  12.,  -7.,  60.],
       [  3.,   6.,  -1.,  63.],
       [  2.,   6.,   3.,  63.]])
```

n is what i want.

Comment: Demonstrate how you would do this with a small regular `numpy` array.  With a good working example we can then worry about whether the sparse matrix needs any special handling.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please check, added an example around how we can do it in case of numpy arrays.

Comment: Could you give some context as to why you need this as a somewhat higher level? My intuition is that by rethinking the problem a bit it may be mapped to numpy operations much more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple demonstration of what I think you are trying to do:

First the numpy array version:

```
In [619]: arr=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [620]: arr[[1,0,2,3]]-arr[0] 
Out[620]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

Now the sparse equivalent:

```
In [622]: M=sparse.csr_matrix(arr)
```

`csr` implements row indexing:

```
In [624]: M[[1,0,2,3]]
Out[624]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [625]: M[[1,0,2,3]].A
Out[625]: 
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]], dtype=int32)
```

But not broadcasting:

```
In [626]: M[[1,0,2,3]]-M[0]
 ....
ValueError: inconsistent shapes
```

So we can use an explicit form of broadcasting

```
In [627]: M[[1,0,2,3]]-M[[0,0,0,0]]  # or M[[0]*4]
Out[627]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [628]: _.A
Out[628]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [9, 9, 9]], dtype=int32)
```

This may not be the fastest or most efficient, but it's a start.

I found in a previous SO question that `M[[1,0,2,3]]` indexing is performed with a matrix multiplication, in this case the equivalent of:

```
idxM = sparse.csr_matrix(([1,1,1,1],([0,1,2,3],[1,0,2,3])),(4,4))
M1 = idxM * M
```

[Sparse matrix slicing using list of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500649/sparse-matrix-slicing-using-list-of-int/39500986#39500986)

So my difference expression requires 2 such multiplication along with the subtraction.

We could try a row by row iteration, and building a new matrix from the result, but there's no guarantee that it will be faster.  Depending on the arrays, converting to dense and back might even be faster.

=================

I can imagine 2 ways of applying this to the dictionary.

One is to iterate through the dictionary (what order?), perform this difference for each key, collect the results in a list (list of sparse matrices), and use `sparse.bmat` to join them into one matrix.

Another is to collect two lists of indexes, and apply the above indexed difference just once.

```
In [8]: index_dictionary = {0: [2, 4], 1: [3, 4], 2: [1], 3: [1, 2], 4: [1, 3, 2]} 
In [10]: alist=[]
    ...: for index in index_dictionary:
    ...:     for k in index_dictionary[index]:
    ...:         alist.append((index, k))       
In [11]: idx = np.array(alist)
In [12]: idx
Out[12]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 1],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 2]])
```

applied to your dense `s`:

```
In [15]: s = np.array([[1,5,3,4],[3,0,12,7],[5,6,2,4],[4,6,6,4],[7,12,5,67]])
In [16]: s[idx[:,0]]-s[idx[:,1]]
Out[16]: 
array([[ -4,  -1,   1,   0],
       [ -6,  -7,  -2, -63],
       [ -1,  -6,   6,   3],
       [ -4, -12,   7, -60],
       [  2,   6, -10,  -3],
       [  1,   6,  -6,  -3],
       [ -1,   0,   4,   0],
       [  4,  12,  -7,  60],
       [  3,   6,  -1,  63],
       [  2,   6,   3,  63]])
```

and to the sparse equivalent

```
In [19]: arr= sparse.csr_matrix(s)
In [20]: arr
Out[20]: 
<5x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 19 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [21]: res=arr[idx[:,0]]-arr[idx[:,1]]
In [22]: res
Out[22]: 
<10x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 37 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: This is perfect!! Thanks:)