# Sparse matrix slicing memory error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix `csr`:

```
<681881x58216 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2867209 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

And i want to create a new sparce matrix as a slice of `csr`:
`csr_2 = csr[1::2,:]`.

**Problem:** When i have `csr` matrix only, my server's RAM is busy with 40 GB. When i run the `csr_2 = csr[1::2,:]`, my server's RAM is being dumped completly for 128GB and it falls with "Memory error".

Comment: Your matrix itself in your example is just 22MB (values) + some aux-stuff, probably <80MB of memory. So are you sure, that's the source of your problem (something else on your server is probably using 39GB of memory)? (and slicing sparse-matrices will induce a copy by the way)

Comment: (1) This slice take each element after other, starting from the second element(odd elements). (2) Server has lots of docker fcontainers and other maintaining processes running all together taking 40GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sparse` uses matrix multiplication to select rows like this.  I worked out the details of the `extractor` matrix in another SO question, but roughly to get a (p, n) matrix from a (m, n) one, it needs to use a (p, m) matrix (with `p` nonzero values).

Matrix multiplication itself is a 2 pass process.  The first pass determines the size of the resulting matrix.

In contrast to dense `numpy` arrays, sparse matrix slicing never returns a view.

[Sparse matrix slicing using list of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500649/sparse-matrix-slicing-using-list-of-int)

has details on the extractor matrix.  I also suggest testing `csr.sum(axis=1)`, since that too uses matrix multiplication.

---

```
def extractor(indices, N):
   indptr=np.arange(len(indices)+1)
   data=np.ones(len(indices))
   shape=(len(indices),N)
   return sparse.csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr), shape=shape)
```

So indexing every other row requires:

```
In [99]: M = sparse.random(100,80,.1, 'csr')
In [100]: M
Out[100]: 
<100x80 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 800 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [101]: E = extractor(np.r_[1:100:2],100)
In [102]: E
Out[102]: 
<50x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 50 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [103]: M1 = E*M
In [104]: M1
Out[104]: 
<50x80 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 407 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: So, the solution you propose is to use the extractor function?

Comment: No, I'm just suggesting a reason why you could be getting the memory error. But without your data, ram, etc I can't prove it.